# Как сделать подобную верстку людей?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

[image: люди]

Как сделать подобную верстку людей. Чем это реализовать?

Comment: флексами, как вариант

Comment: попробуй изучить свойства display:flex и display:grid на ютубе

Answer (score 8):

[Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout)

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
}
.grid h1 {
  font-size: 8vw;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 0;
}
.grid p {
  margin: 0;
}
.grid p:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.grid__title {
  grid-column: 1/4;
}
.grid__desc {
  grid-column: 1/3;
}
.grid__image {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.grid__image-block {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.grid__image-block::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 100%;
}
.grid__image-block--blue {
  background-color: #154ae4;
}
.grid__image-block--red {
  background-color: #e72450;
}
.grid__desc,
.grid__disclaimer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<section class="grid">
  <div class="grid__title">
    <h1>Prawdziwe<br>historie</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="grid__image">
    <div class="grid__image-block grid__image-block--blue"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid__desc">
    <p>Zapraszamy do lektury histonl klncntów, partnerów I przyjaciół. z ktorymi marny przyjemność wçdrować drogą rozwoju i przedsiębiorczości.</p>
    <p>Każda historia jest inna, bo stoją za nimi unikalne organizacje tworzone przez ludzi obdarzonych wyjątkowymi pomysłami, talentami i doświadczeniami.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid__image">
    <div class="grid__image-block grid__image-block--blue"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid__image">
    <div class="grid__image-block grid__image-block--red"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid__span"></div>
  <div class="grid__image">
    <div class="grid__image-block grid__image-block--blue"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid__image">
    <div class="grid__image-block grid__image-block--red"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid__image">
    <div class="grid__image-block grid__image-block--blue"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid__image">
    <div class="grid__image-block grid__image-block--blue"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid__image">
    <div class="grid__image-block grid__image-block--red"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid__disclaimer">
    <p>"Jesteśmy złączeni dzięki historiom" - Arystoteles, 384-322 p.n.e.</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

bootstrap grid -- В ней 12 колонок, как раз для 4 картинок идеально
создаешь container, в нем row,
далее col-9 -- в нем текст, оставшийся col-3 -под картинку
с подписями делать так:
в col-3 создаешь row, а в нем col и пишешь нужный текст

Comment: Я бы советовал сначала `html` и `css` изучить, а уже потом использовать фреймворки.